# Corona SDK - While Statement

Tags: loops, sdk, while-loop, coronasdk

I'm pretty new to Corona SDK and I need to know how to get a while statement.. If someone could tell me how to get one, that would be great. I Googled it, and I couldn't find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while condition do
--code here
end
```